# Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference at ctrl.getplaceholder in ui-select.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-select

[image]

Hello I am implementing ui-select angular directive for multiple auto complete. with angular version 1.2.18 it workes fine but when i used with angular 1.5.5  getting an Error like :
Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference at ctrl.getplaceholder

My Html Code is :

```
<ui-select multiple tagging="tagTransform" tagging-tokens="SPACE|,|/" ng-model="demo.selectedPeople" style="width: 800px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}">
        <div ng-if="person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name + ' ' + $select.taggingLabel | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <div ng-if="!person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name| highlight: $select.search"></div>

    </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

My Controller Code is:

```
lampiApp.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


$scope.tagTransform = function (newTag) {
    var item = {
        name: newTag,

    };

    return item;
};

$scope.people=[];
var str = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October singh";
var splittedString = str.split(',');
var arr = [];
splittedString.forEach(function (v) {
    arr.push({ name: v });
});

$scope.people = arr;

});
```

Comment: i think the error is at placeholder value fetching part $item.name .. use $select.selected.value instead

Comment: remove multiple attribute .. also i don't know what exactly your are facing

Comment: sir i am implemention ui-select with angular version 1.2.18 it works fine when i use it with version 1.5.5 it gives an error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference at ctrl.getplaceholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.This was the Error that is related to angular version i figure out the solution by myself , see it at this Plnkr
2.http://plnkr.co/edit/230zLWeyACfReVaPZ0LM?p=preview
```